# How to compile the BeanShell sampler in jmeter, before runnig it

Tags: automation, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, beanshell

So here is what i am looking for.
When ever I write code in jmeter BeanShell sampler I always end up in compile time errors and I spend lot of time in debugging and fixing them.

So is there any way to compile it before runnig it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have you tried running `java -jar bsh-2.0b6.jar` from "lib" folder of your JMeter installation?  It will kick off [Beanshell Desktop](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/desktop.html) where you will be able to validate your code.

Second, it is **[interpreted](http://www.beanshell.org/javadoc/bsh/Interpreter.html)** therefore you cannot compile it, if you want syntax highlighting and linting you can consider i.e. [Beanshell editor plugin for Eclipse](https://github.com/evplatt/BshEditor) or [BeanShell Box
for Idea](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/1022-beanshell-box)

Third, [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) as the language so it's right time to consider moving to Groovy as it can be compiled with any modern IDE, moreover Groovy performs much better than Beanshell. Check out [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.